# Microsoft Graph API $filter=name eq 'foo' query not working on GET workbook/tables/{id}/columns. No error and no filtering

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files, microsoft-graph-excel

I'm looking at a table (`Table1`) inside an Excel book saved on my OneDrive for Business account. I then want to get the maximum value in the `CREATEDDATE` column from this table.

I want to avoid pulling down the whole table with the API, so I'm trying to filter the results of my query to only the `CREATEDDATE` column. However, the column results from the table are not being filtered to the one column and I'm not getting an error to help troubleshoot why. All I get is an `HTTP 200` response and the full unfiltered table results.

Is it possible to filter the columns retrieved from the API by the column name? The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) made me think so.

I've confirmed that `/columns?$select=name` works correctly and returns just the name field, so I know that it recognizes this as an entity. `$filter` and `$orderby` do nothing when referencing any of the entities from the response (`name`, `id`, `index`, `values`). I know that I can limit columns by position, but I'd rather explicitly reference the column by name in case the order changes.

I'm using this query:

```
/v1.0/me/drive/items/{ID}/workbook/tables/Table1/columns?$filter=name eq 'CREATEDDATE'`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `$filter` here, just pull it by the name directly. The prototypes from the [Get TableColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tablecolumn-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs#request-headers) documentation are:

```
GET /workbook/tables/{id|name}/columns/{id|name}
GET /workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/tables/{id|name}/columns/{id|name}
```

So in your case, you should be able to simply call call:

```
/v1.0/me/drive/items/{ID}//workbook/tables/Table1/columns/CREATEDDATE
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you!
edit: can't upvote yet, sorry